# Jpackage issues - Not running

Tags: java, swing, jpackage

I should preface this by saying I'm a novice who got in way too deep trying to make a Swing app an exe. After reading the docs I've sort of gleaned what the meanings of all the parameters are, but I'm still confused. What I'm trying to achieve is an application that can be double clicked and launch the GUI, without creating a JRE (if it is not necessary) No jfx so it is non modular.

I tried to use these following commands:

```
jpackage --type app-image -i "C:\Users\User\quadAdventGame\out\artifacts\quadAdventGame_jar" -n quadGameTest --main-class Main --main-jar quadAdventGame.jar
```

Then using that app image:

```
jpackage -n name --app-image "C:\Users\User\quadGameTest"
```

This resulted in two things: The installer ran, Norton Antivirus flagged it, saying it stopped the process, and then I told Norton to let it go. Then the installer failed to run, saying it had no access to "main.msi" in my Local disk. I also tried direct msi installing,

```
jpackage --type msi -i "C:\Users\User\quadAdventGame\out\artifacts\quadAdventGame_jar" -n quadGameTest --main-class Main --main-jar quadAdventGame.jar
```

which simply doesn't run when double clicked.

[BTW, here's what the generated folder looks like, which seems like it may be wrong.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqs39.png)

My questions would be:

- Is Norton some how involved in the stoppage of my app from running? I'm not sure what Main.msi is in my temp folder.
- Are my commands wrong? It seems like they are not correct for what I want to achieve, which is just a simple runnable application. The code is baby stuff, this is literally just me trying to prove I can do this. Does the main class input need to have the .java prefix? It honestly might be me just naming stuff wrong, but the generated folders have a jar that runs fine.
- If so, how can these commands be remedied?
  I am on the Oracle JDK 14.

Comment: Sounds like your antivirus may be the issue. Try temporarily disabling it, or see whether EXE format has same problem, or as jpackage is incubator release in JDK14 it may be worth trying in JDK17.

Comment: @DuncG Ill try both. Ive already tried exe format. I keep getting an incubator warning, in JDK 14 what does that mean? Is JDK 17 more stable?

Comment: jpackage is non-incubator from JDK16, and like all software, problems found in earlier releases may be resolved in later versions.

Comment: @DuncG hi. Sorry to keep bothering you. I tried exe format and it didn’t work, but I did seem to find the problem, outlined here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73231076/linkageerror-in-jpackage-unsupportedclassversionerror

Any ideas